# iOS Enable backup for file ONLY IF backup is encrypted

Tags: ios, encryption, backup

I know I can flag files or data with `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` to exclude it from an iTunes Backup. I'm wondering if there is a way, I can mark data as eligible for **encrypted** backup only?

I'm assuming it must be possible as it seems to be the logic that HealthKit uses ([HealthKit is losing people's data](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8382573))